# Remote Desktop switch workspaces on host (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, workspace

I have two machines, both windows 10, I'm remoted into one machine. On the local machine I have multiple workspaces and can switch between them using Ctrl + Win + left/right arrows, really snazzy.

However if I get into a full screen remote desktop session, then its workspaces want to take over; I can't find a way to disable this and allow me to control my local workspaces, any more. Nor am I finding any shortcut keys that allow me to push the windows key locally.

Am I missing something, or did Microsoft not really think about this use case?

Comment: If the remote desktop session is NOT full screen, then the inputs will go to the local session. If the Remote Desktop session is full-screen, then the inputs go to the remote session. I think of the full-screen mode as a "modal dialog" mode, so in this case it makes sense that the input gets directed to the remote session.

Comment: @cdavid yeah, I was afraid of that, there are SOME special host shortcut keys that you can access the local session while in the remote session (such as the full screen shortcut key). I was hoping that Microsoft put something in for workspaces or a 3rd party tool that I could use...

Comment: This was answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1046767/windows-10-switch-virtual-deskop-while-in-fullscreen-remote-desktop

Answer (score -1):

I found your question while seeking the same.

Best workaround I have is the following combo

[ctrl] + [alt] + [pause/break] : this will full screen/window the remote desktop

I put my remote sessions on separate desktops and use the 
[ctrl] + [win] + right/left

I wonder if something can be done using AutoHotKey to wrap it up into a single action?

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).

Comment: Actually this is my working solution so it IS an answer to the original question.