# Creating a fake display on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, external-display

I need to create a fake dysplay on my main pc to remotely conect with my notebook and use it as a second screen.

I cant use a headless ghost, cause my computer only have um vga output(intel integrated graphics) and is in use, so it have to be made on the software side.

After some update, all of this methods doest seen to works:

[Can a fake second display be enabled in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/947291/can-a-fake-second-display-be-enabled-in-windows-10)

[Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor)

Comment: Check this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/1046767/windows-10-switch-virtual-deskop-while-in-fullscreen-remote-desktop).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor)

Comment: already tried, doest work on the latest windows 10 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SpaceDesk](https://www.spacedesk.net/) creates virtual monitor for every client that connects to your pc through spacedesk client, so you can have multiple displays that aren't really exists and it works fine on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SpaceDesk requires that at least one of the computers has a different version than Windows 10 installed.

If you are using Windows 10 on all the computers you need to connect, you may find a solution by installing **Microsoft Garage Mouse without Borders**, a free tool which allows you to control up to four computers from a single mouse and keyboard.
By using it I succeeded in having three work areas instead than two; more specifically, I have my main laptop connected to an external monitor phisically, then I connected it to my tablet by using *Microsoft Garage Mouse without Borders* and I use it as a third external monitor. They both have Windows 10 installed on them.

You may do the following:

1) download *Microsoft Garage Mouse without Borders* from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460). You will install it on all the computers you want to connect (in my case the main laptop and the tablet);

2) Install and run it on the secondary device first (my tablet, in my case) and follow the instructions; it will ask you if you've already installed it on the other devices, you have to select "No";

3) an ID and a password will be shown at this point: you want to save them for later;

4) Run and install it on the main device (my laptop, in my case);

5) When it will ask whether or not you've already installed it on the other devices you want to select "yes"; **you have to enter the ID and the password** previously shown on the previous device.

6) the devices are now connected: you can now copy text or drag and drop files across computers.

Answer (score -1):

What I did is that I downloaded Bluestack, installed spacedesk on it and spacedesk on my pc. Bluestack then becomes your second screen. You must just go to display setting to tell windows that you are extending the display. You will realize that Windows now sees two screens.