# How to mock up a virtual display on a Windows 10 VM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, graphics-card, display-settings, monitor-settings

Running from an amazon VM with windows 10, I want to mirror the screen with an application through a web interface.

Ideally I would like to Mock up a custom screen that mirrors the clients resolution, in order to send a picture that would result in a full screen web page.

There is a basic default VGA monitor available with the VM, but this is not configurable. And is useless in regards to color resolution and dimmensions.

It looks like the normal solution to mock up a fake screen is to buy a fake plug an put into the screen card, which I obiously cannot do an a virtual Amazon server. [1](https://superuser.com/questions/947291/can-a-fake-second-display-be-enabled-in-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1286758/creating-a-fake-display-on-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My question is: 
**Are there any good software in existance for mocking up a screen or an entire graphics card virtually. Or a native trick in windows 10 that can do it without having physical display ports available?**

Comment: Logging in to the VM with RDP allows you ignore the VM's "physical" display and render at the configured desktop resolution in your RDP client settings, but Windows treats an RDP "display" slightly different and disables several display settings and fullscreen 3D. Maybe that will work just enough for what you need?

Comment: The problem is that my use case would need to be to run on a monitor mirroring a random webpage users monitor. Hence, it has to be swappable in an instance without human interaction. But thanks for the thought!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following free products create a virtual screen and could perhaps be a solution.
You will need to see if they work under this particular environment.

- [**spacedesk**](https://spacedesk.net/)
  A primary machine runs a Windows service and the WDDM driver that appears
  as an additional graphics adapter to Windows 10 whose contents
  are captured, compressed and transmitted over the LAN to the spacedesk
  secondary machine(s).
- [**ZoneScreen**](https://zoneos.com/zonescreen/)
  ZoneScreen consists of two parts: kernel-mode ZoneScreen Virtual Display Driver
  emulating a video card with monitor attached to it, and user-mode ZoneScreen Wizard
  running server side and responsible for capturing the image, transmitting it over
  the network, and drawing it at another computer (called client).
  The client machine has only the ZoneScreen Wizard running in client mode.

Comment: This last alternative sounds interesting. I will look into that. Spacedesk has been tried without luck :) Thanks!

Comment: I have not a chance to test it yet, but I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: The ZoneScreen option seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks! 

The only thing I did not figure out, was how to set a custom resolution if the screen options listed is not suitable. In other regards the solution looks awsomme.